# MoveFile and MoveFileEx works weird if filenames are the same in DOS 8.3 style

Tags: c, windows, winapi

Ok, I have files named

```
ANIME~1.MKV~FNH47B97
ANIME~1.MKV
```

It is FULL filenames. It is named so by user.
And I want to rename the first one to ANIME~1.JPG. From OS point of view they seem to be the same files. And both MoveFile and MoveFileEx do nothing. They return OK and that's all.
Another weird situation is when we have, for example,

```
ANIME~2.MKV~FNH47B97
ANIME~3.MKV
```

And I want to rename the first one to ANIME~2.MKV
OS founds that it's the same as ANIME~3.MKV and still does nothing.
It depends on the number of files with "the same dos 8.3 names" in the folder

Any way to workaround it? May be some additional actions/flags needed?

Comment: `MoveFile` and `MoveFileEx` are designed to work on the full filename, not the 8.3 one. The 8.3 variant is **optionally** generated for long filenames, but this generation can also be turned off.

Comment: Of course I use FULL filenames. It is named by user so. Full filenames and full path

Comment: In the second case, you obviously can not move the file to its new name because it clashes with the (short?) name of an existing file.

Comment: And no way to disable DOS8.3 compatibility?

Comment: I tested the first situation with two files and it works fine for me. The first file gets renamed, but again this only works if there are no name clashes with any long or short filenames.

Comment: You can disable it for an NTFS volume, but I wouldn't recommend it. Furthermore, that's something the system admin should decide, not an application.

Comment: I agree with you. It's the first time I met such situation with user files. Please mark it as question and if possible - provide info about disabling on partition level just for future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarise the discussion in the comments as an approximate answer: `MoveFile(Ex)` works on the full filenames, though it can find the source file by its short name, the destination file is taken to be the long name.

This means that the destination filename should not clash with any long or short filenames of existing files. This is probably why your second test-case fails.
The first test-case probably fails for a similar reason; I've tried it with just those two files and `MoveFile` works with it.

It is possible to disable the generation of DOS style 8.3 shortnames, see [KB121007](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/121007), but I really don't recommend it. It can cause lots of issues, see for instance [this article](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/windows-7/How-wreck-your-Windows-network-Part2.html). Also, this is a decision that should be left to the system administrator, not any application.